# Python reduce function not working the way it is expected

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very simple use case in which i have a list of names and i have to calculate the total length of all the words in the names list. Below is my code base but it does not work the way i expect :

```
In [13]: names = ['John', 'Arya', 'Maya', 'Mary']                                                                                                                             

In [14]: from functools import reduce                                                                                                                                         

In [15]: check = reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) + len(y), names)                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-39802d43150a> in <module>
----> 1 check = reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) + len(y), names)

<ipython-input-15-39802d43150a> in <lambda>(x, y)
----> 1 check = reduce(lambda x, y: len(x) + len(y), names)

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Can someone please point out where i am going wrong .

Comment: you should probably read about [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) and its signature

Comment: The first argument is the accumulator, and you should also provide `initial=0`: `reduce(lambda x, y: x + len(y), names, 0)` will output 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a generator expression with `sum`. `reduce` will only sometimes be better or clearer for specific use cases.

```
names = ['John', 'Arya', 'Maya', 'Mary']
total_length = sum(len(name) for name in names)
```

If you do want to use `reduce`, the first parameter is the accumulated value and the second is the next element of the list. You'll need to provide a starting value and only call `len` on the your `y` value:

```
total_length = reduce(lambda x, y: x + len(y), names, 0)
```

Comment: just found the ans. We can also do it this way : check = len(''.join(names))

Comment: @user1867151: it doesn't sound reasonable to allocate memory for a throw-away string just to obtain its length

Comment: Yes @AzatIbrakov i guess you are right, i will go with the reduce approach.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness thought I'd also show `map`, a more functional approach:

```
total_length = sum(map(len, names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure-python implementation of `reduce()`:

```
>>> def reduce(fun, seq, initial=0):
...     acc = initial
...     for item in seq:
...         acc = fun(acc, item)
...     return acc
```

We can see that `fun()` receives the accumulator and the current value from `seq`. This is apparent when you trace the execution:

```
>>> def foo(x, y):
...     print("foo(%s, %s) -> %s" % (x, y, x+y))
...     return x+y
... 
>>> reduce(foo, range(6))
foo(0, 1) -> 1
foo(1, 2) -> 3
foo(3, 3) -> 6
foo(6, 4) -> 10
foo(10, 5) -> 15
15
```